# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$ converge to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was solving a problem in real analysis where the author used the below to support his argument.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} = 0$$

Is the above limit valid ?

It struck me that, as $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form, can we say that the above limit holds?
Possible known values to which $1^\infty$ can go are $1$, $e$, and $\infty$ . Can we substantiate and say that the above limit holds?

Comment: it's sandwiched by $\dfrac{-1}n$ and $\dfrac 1n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author is correct.  It is [sandwiched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)
between $\dfrac{-1}n$ and $\dfrac 1n$.

Comment: Thanks @J.W. Tanner !

Answer (score 2):

Here it is a proof which is not based on the sandwich theorem for the sake of curiosity.

**Proposition**

Let $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then $a_{n}$ converges to $0$ iff $|a_{n}|$ converges to zero.

**Proof**

We shall prove the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ first.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow ||a_{n}| - 0| = |a_{n} - 0| \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}
from which we conclude that $|a_{n}|$ converges to zero.

Similar reasoning applies to the implication $(\Leftarrow)$.

**Solution**

Since $|a_{n}| = 1/n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$, we conclude that $a_{n}$ converges to zero as well.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: In the proof part , why didn't you mention Archimedian axiom ?

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I should have done it. But I assume you know that $1/n$ converges to zero as $n$ approaches infinity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. !

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad to help.